# Unable to create class vector of structs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create an empty vector of structs. I will be adding elements at runtime with push_back().

The overall structure is a separate class has a vector of Resource objects, and each Resource object is supposed to have this struct vector, pipeline. I don't understand why this declaration is not being treated as a regular class variable. In Resource.cpp, the hint vscode gives me mentions something about an allocator. I neither know what that is, nor know how it applies.

Resource.h

```
#include <vector>

class Resource {
    public:
    int typeSize;
    typedef struct PipelineSlot{
        bool isBusy;        
        uint32_t busyCycle; 
        Instruction *occupiedBy; 
    } pls_t;
    std::vector<pls_t> pipeline; //why doesn't this create a class variable?

    static bool pushFU(Instruction* instr, int cycle, std::vector<Resource> &fuVector);
};
```

Resource.cpp

```
#include <Resource.h>
typedef struct PipelineSlot pls_t;

static bool pushFU(Instruction* instr, int cycle, std::vector<Resource> &fuVector) {
    for (auto fu : fuVector) { 
        std::vector<pls_t> pipe = fu.pipeline; //IDE doesn't like this
        if (fu.pipeline.size() > 0) { 
            if (fu.pipeline.back().busyCycle != cycle && fu.pipeline.size() < Resource::resourceLatency.find(fu.type)->second) { 
                pls_t newInstr {true, cycle, instr};
                fu.pipeline.push_back(newInstr); //IDE doesn't like this
                return true;
            }
        } else if (fu.pipeline.size() == 0) {
            pls_t newInstr {true, cycle, instr};
            fu.pipeline.push_back(newInstr); //IDE doesn't like this
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but IDE only has an issue with the push_back() calls, not with the other vector methods (which I also don't understand). **The end goal is to have a class vector of structs that I can modify at run time.** How do I achieve this?

EDIT: VSCode gives me this hint when I hover over the push_back() lines:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>push_back [with _Tp=Resource::pls_t, Alloc=std::allocator<Resource::pls_t]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (pls_t) -- object type is: std::vector<Resource::pls_t, std::allocator<Resource::pls_t>>
```

Compiler tells me this (lots of these errors):

```
error: ‘class Resource’ has no member named ‘pipeline’; did you mean ‘typeSize’?
             if (fu.pipeline.size() > 0) { behavior
```

Note: I am a college student with a background in c, but am VERY new with c++.

Comment: You should post the errors, not just say "IDE doesn't like this".  It isn't the IDE that is giving the error, it is the compiler.  Also `typedef struct` is not necessary in a C++ program -- all you need is `struct`.

Comment: You need a semi colon at the end of your class

Comment: updated with error messages and additional class information

Comment: You need to compile your code and get the proper error messages. The ones generated by the ide are more hints that something is wrong, the compiler output will be more detailed and accurate

Comment: You want to update `fu`, so you should refer to element of vector by reference: `auto& fu` in *for* loop.

Comment: The compiler error messages are quite clear: https://godbolt.org/z/kG6rFp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the fundamental error

```
class Resource
{
    typedef struct PipelineSlot {
        bool isBusy;        
        uint32_t busyCycle; 
        Instruction *occupiedBy; 
    } pls_t;
};
```

Because `PipelineSlot` is inside the `Resource` class the names created here are `Resource::PipelineSlot` and `Resource::pls_t`, not (as you seem to think) `PipelineSlot` and `pls_t`.

Outside of the `Resource` class `PipelineSlot` and `pls_t` must be qualified with `Resource::`. So this code would work

```
std::vector<Resource::pls_t> pipe = fu.pipeline;
```

So would moving the struct outside of the `Resource` class. That's probably what you should do.

But then you've confused things even further by creating a new typedef `typedef struct PipelineSlot pls_t;`. This is a completely different definition from the previous one, because it is given outside the `Resource` class, and the types declared here `PipelineSlot` and `pls_t` have no relation at all to the previously declared types.

Comment: That worked! So even though the functions are inside the resource header and class declaration, they aren't in the namespace? Why is that?

Comment: @nquartz It seems you have another confusion. You have two functions called `pushFu`. The one in the header is `Resource::pushFu` but the one in the cpp file is plain `pushFu`. You are correct, if the function you actually wrote had been `Resource::pushFu` then you would not have needed to qualify the other names.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
std::vector<Resource::pls_t> pipe = fu.pipeline;
```